# CORS issue between React web page and Azure API

Tags: reactjs, azure, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I created an API with .NET Core 2.2 and later deployed in Azure API Management service. Then I configured the API to execute only for valid access tokens. I enabled also cors in this configuration:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
        <openid-config url="https://myTenant.b2clogin.com/myTenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_react_signup" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>APP-Id-999999999999999999999</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>https://myTenant.b2clogin.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/</issuer>
        </issuers>
    </validate-jwt>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="webAPI" />
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>http://localhost:3000</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
        </allowed-methods>
    </cors>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

In the front-end, I have a web app that runs with React and Express. The app runs in my local server: http:/localhost:3000

When I execute my Azure policy (user flow) "B2C_1_react_signup" to login, then I get a valid access token and I am able to execute the API from postman putting in the headers: Authorization as key and the access token as a value. That works without any CORS issues.

When I try to do the same from the page, the authentication goes to the Azure B2C website, if the authentication succeeds it redirects to my page (http://localhost:3000) and I see in the localStorage of the browser the access_token and id_token.

This is the error I got from the console:

Access to fetch at 'https://myAPI.azure-api.net/api/private' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is my code in react:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Auth from "./Auth/Auth";

class Private extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.auth = new Auth();
  }

 state = {
   message: ""
 };

componentDidMount() {
  this.idToken = this.auth.getTokens().idToken;

console.log("");
console.log("ID TOKEN: " + this.idToken);
console.log("");

fetch("https://myAPI.azure-api.net/api/private", {
  headers: { Authorization: `${this.idToken}` }
})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) return response.json();
    throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
  })
  .then(response => this.setState({ message: response }))
  .catch(error => this.setState({ message: error.message }));
}

render() {
  return <p>{this.state.message}</p>;
 }
}

export default Private;
```

Note the Id_token of this line is correct:

```
headers: { Authorization: `${this.idToken}` }
```

If I copy it and paste in the postman, without Bearer it jus work.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this? Should I modify my .NET Web API and enable CORS there then deploy in azure again? Why the CORS policy in Azure does not work?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @MarcosF8, how's going? Has this issue been solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was sending a wrong token. So I got this confusing CORS error, but it was an authorization error actually. I was able to see the http request I do from the browser and I realized I was doing a conversion wrong in my code that resulted in a wrong token.

Comment: Could you,please point out exactly the error you are making ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is no `<allowed-headers>` tag defined in your policy.But there is a `Authorization`  header in your request , so try the policy below :

```html
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>http://localhost:3000/</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>Authorization</header>
        </allowed-headers>
    </cors>
```

If there will be additional http request headers , pls try to add them to `allowed-headers` element too.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Where I put this policy?

Comment: @ShoshanaTzi,just see this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies